# Content security policy and whitelist unsafe-eval

Tags: security, web, content-security-policy

Is it possible to configure "content security policy" for domains like `*.googleapis.com` where I'll have `unsafe-eval` enabled, but for my own website (`self`) it will be disabled?

I looked at the doc, Internet, RFCs for hours and found nothing about that. Seems like it's impossible, wanted to ask community.

Comment: You can’t enable unsafe-eval per-source. See, e.g., item 1 in the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10944794/csp-how-to-allow-unsafe-eval-for-a-given-uri-prefix-firefox/10949133#10949133